# Why does these following sets open or close?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Could someone tell me if there is any mistake in my explanation of following statement?

(1) $(0,1)∪(2,4)$ is an open set in $\Bbb R$.

> Because for all points in the set we can find an open ball centered at the point.

(2) $[0,1]∪[2,4]$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R$ (do it in two diﬀerent ways).

> Because 1.It includes all limit points.
>           2.The complement is open.

(3) $(0,1]$ is neither open nor closed in $\Bbb R$.

> Because the left side does not contain the limit point 0 and also we cannot find an open ball centered at 1 that is contained completely in the set.

(4) Explain why $\Bbb R$ is both open and closed in $\Bbb R$.

> Because it contains all the limit points(by completeness) and for all points in $\Bbb R$ there is a neighbourhood that is completely contained in $\Bbb R$.

I fell not sure about the following 3. Could someone explain it explicitly just by using the following definition and theorem?

**Deﬁnition.** A set $A ⊂\Bbb R$ is open if for every $a ∈ A$ there exists $ε > 0$ such that the open interval $(a−ε,a + ε) ⊂ A$.

**Deﬁnition.** A set $A ⊂\Bbb R$ is closed if its complement $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is open.

**Theorem.** A set $A ⊂\Bbb R$ is closed if, and only if, for every sequence $(a_n)^∞_{n=1}$ in $A$ such that $a_n → a$, we have $a ∈ A$. That is, an equivalent deﬁnition for a closed set in $\Bbb R$ is that it contains all its limit points.

**Deﬁnition.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A set $A ⊂ X$ is open if for every $a ∈ A$ there exists $ε > 0$ such that the open ball $B(a,ε) ⊂ A$.

**Deﬁnition.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A set $A ⊂ X$ is closed if its complement $X\setminus A$ is open.

**Theorem.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A set $A ⊂ X$ is closed if, and only if, for every sequence $(a_n)^∞_{n=1}$ in $A$ such that $a_n → a$, we have $a ∈ A$. That is, an equivalent deﬁnition for a closed set in $X$ is that it contains all its limit points.

(5) $(0,1)∪(2,4)$ is a closed set in the metric space $(0,1)∪(2,4)$.

(6) $[0,1]∪[2,4]$ is an open set in the metric space $[0,1]∪[2,4]$.

(7) $(0,1]$ is both open and closed in the metric space $(0,1]$.

Many thanks!

Comment: You should split up this question.

Comment: Under (4) you argue that $\mathbb R$ is closed because it contains all limit points. That it is correct on its own, but what you add between brackets: "(by completeness)" is not correct. E.g. $\mathbb Q$ is closed in $\mathbb Q$ but is not complete.

Comment: @drhab  Actually I cannot agree that Q is closed. Because it does not contain all its limit points. For instance, I think I can choose the sequence in Q whose limit is sqrt(2).

Comment: @Y.X. What you are saying is that $\mathbb Q$ is not a closed subset of $\mathbb R$, and you are right in that. But what I am saying is that $\mathbb Q$ is closed in $\mathbb Q$. That is true (every topological space $X$ is closed in $X$) in spite of the fact that there are Cauchy-sequences in $\mathbb Q$  that have no limit in $\mathbb Q$ (so $\mathbb Q$ is not complete).

Comment: For (1) your sentence is incomplete.It should say "For every $x\in S=(0,1)\cup (2,4)$ we can find an open ball $B$ with $x\in B\subset S.$"..... Now prove this is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All  cases you are unsure of (i.e., (5), (6), (7)) are a consequence of:

> If $X$ is a metric space then $X$ is both open and closed, and $\emptyset$ is both open and closed.

Note that $X$ is open because for every $a\in X$, the open ball $B(a,1)=\{\,y\in X\mid d(x,y)<1\,\}$ is a subset of $X$. And $\emptyset$ is vacuously open. Hence their complements $\emptyset$ and $X$ are closed.

Comment: Could you please give a formal proof that metric spaces are both open and closed by definition?

Comment: Moreover, is there any difference between saying a SET is closed or open in a METRIC SPACE and the SET is closed (without mention the metric space)? To be more precise, is there any subtle differences between the statements:1. This SET is closed. 2. This METRIC SPACE is closed. 3. This set is closed in this metric space? I ask this because in the definition of closed and open, it does not mention WHERE is the set is closed in.

Comment: @Y.X. the notion "closed" makes only sense in a context where there is a topology. When asked if set is closed there always has to be some metric space specified (or more generally toplogy, but let is ignore this). This specification is sometimes only implicit. For example, when the subset of the reals are considered the implicit assumption is that the usual metic on the reals is used. The set $(1,2] $ is not closed  in the metric space "real numbers" but it is closed in the  space $(1,5)$ with the usual metric. It may be in the former case the mention of real numbers is not made ecplicit.

Answer (score 0):

Re: Equivalent def'n of "$A$ is closed" :

If $x$ is a limit point of $A,$  then for all $e>0$ we have $(-e+x,e+x)\cap A\ne \phi.$ So if $x\not \in A$ then $x\in \mathbb R$ \ $A$ and for all $e>0$ we have $(-e+x,e+x)\not \subset \mathbb R$ \ $A.$ So $\mathbb R$ \ $A$ is not open, so $A$ is not closed.

If $A$ contains all its limit points then for every $y\in \mathbb R$ \ $A$ there exists $e_y>0$ such that $(-e_y+y,e_y+y)\cap A=\phi.$ (Otherwise $y$ would be a limit point of $A,$ or a member of $A.$) So for every $y\in \mathbb R$ \  $A$ there exists $e_y>0$ such that $(-e_y+y,e_y+y)\subset \mathbb R$ \ $A.$ That is, $\mathbb R$ \ $A$ is open. So $A$ is closed.